# Is there any option to convert datetime value to DD-MM-YYYY HH-MM AM/PM this format in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

How can I get 2nd column format in SQL Server 2008?

For example:

```
SELECT 
    GETDATE() col1,  
    '16-09-2017 11:20 AM' col2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select convert(varchar(10),GETDATE(), 105) + right(convert(varchar(32),GETDATE(),100),8)
```

Comment: Thanks..! me also using like the following.any other simple formats..?select REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),105) +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),
   CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME),100),'PM',' PM'),'AM',' AM')

Answer (score 0):

A handy snippet for such an occasion:

```
DECLARE @i INTEGER = 0
WHILE @i < 255
BEGIN
    SELECT @i += 1
    Declare @out Table (zample varchar(max), aline varchar(max))
    BEGIN TRY
    insert into @out(zample, aline)
        SELECT CAST(n AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ' - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), GETDATE(), n) xZample, 'CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),@MindIfWeDanceWitYoDates, ' + CAST(n AS VARCHAR(25)) + ')' AS _________________________tehcode____________________________
        FROM (SELECT @i AS n) x
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
       --do nothing
        exec(';');
    END CATCH
END
select * from @out
```

Comment: No One format matched to my requirement.Anyway thanks for your interest